# AEM anchor tag stripped out in locahost

Tags: aem

When I use an anchor tag without an href="" all is good and the button style is there, the second a add an href it completely removes the anchor tag and leave only the text inside the parent div

without href:

```
<div class="container">
 <a class="button"> my button</a>
</div>
```

result in browser devtools

```
<div class="container">
 <a class="button"> my button</a>
</div>
```

with href

```
<div class="container">
 <a  href="/content/mypage.html" class="button"> my button</a>
</div>
```

result in browser

```
<div class="container">
 my button
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this could be the work of the link checker. Try adding [`x-cq-linkchecker="skip"`](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/DisableLinkChecker.html):

```html
<div class="container">
 <a x-cq-linkchecker="skip" href="/content/mypage.html" class="button"> my button</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, it still does the same

Comment: Sorry my bad, had a typo. thanks @RaphaelSchweikert

Answer (score 0):

I guess it might be also related to xssconfig

as you add 'href' attribute to div in your example

```html
<div  href="/content/mypage.html" class="container">
 <a class="button"> my button</a>
</div>
```

In general it is not allowed, therefore AEM can remove it
`/libs/cq/xssprotection/config.xml`